# Checking isEmpty data in flutter GridView.builder

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to show a text widget ("No Data Found") in flutter gridview when there is no data. I used nested ternary operator too but not working.

Here is code What I am trying.
Created a gridview widget.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:recipe_app/models/recipe.dart';
import 'package:recipe_app/services/recipe_service.dart';
import 'package:recipe_app/widgets/recipe_by_category.dart';

class RecipesByCategoryName extends StatefulWidget {
  final String categoryName;
  final String categoryIcon;
  final int categoryId;
  RecipesByCategoryName(
      {this.categoryIcon, this.categoryId, this.categoryName});
  @override
  _RecipesByCategoryNameState createState() => _RecipesByCategoryNameState();
}

class _RecipesByCategoryNameState extends State<RecipesByCategoryName> {
  RecipeService _recipesService = RecipeService();
  List<Recipe> _recipeListByCategory = List<Recipe>();
  bool isLoading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getRecipesByCategory();
  }

  _getRecipesByCategory() async {
    var products =
        await _recipesService.getRecipesByCategoryId(widget.categoryId);
    var _list = json.decode(products.body);
    _list["data"].forEach((data) {
      var model = Recipe();
      model.id = data["id"];
      model.title = data["recipeTitle"];
      model.image = data["recipePhoto"];
      model.cookTime = data["cookTime"].toString();
      model.ingredients = data["recipeIngredient"];
      model.directions = data["recipeDirection"];

      setState(() {
          _recipeListByCategory.add(model);
          isLoading = false;
      });
    });
  }

  Widget getGridView(){
    return (_recipeListByCategory?.length != 0) ? GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
      ),
      itemCount: _recipeListByCategory.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return RecipeByCategory(
          this._recipeListByCategory[index],

        );
      },
    ) : Text("No Data Found");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text(this.widget.categoryName)),
        body: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: isLoading
                ? CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
              strokeWidth: 10,
            )
                :
            getGridView()
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Upadated
I want to show a text widget ("No Data Found") in flutter gridview when there is no data. I used nested ternary operator too but not working.

Please take a look into isLoading fuction also.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Show what is happening or what error do you have, also there is no need to wrap your text widget in a center because getGridView is already inside one

Comment: Can you upload the full code?

Comment: @EdwynZN I am not getting any error. only CirculaprogressIndicator is displaying. I can not show Empty text message

Comment: isLoading never be false, that in your case, check the value of it, also have a look when it becomes true

Comment: Can you upload the full code?

Comment: @ShriHari please check updated question

Comment: @JayDangar please check updated question

Comment: can you check if list is empty or not through debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this. It may solve your issue.

```
Widget getGridView(){
   if(_recipeListByCategory.length > 0) {
    return GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
      ),
      itemCount: _recipeListByCategory.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return RecipeByCategory(
          this._recipeListByCategory[index],
        );
      },
    );
   } else{
      return Center(child: Text("No Data Found"),);
  }
}
```

This is because, `isLoading` never becomes false, and in your `async` function, `setState` outside `forEach`

```
_getRecipesByCategory() async {
    var products =
        await _recipesService.getRecipesByCategoryId(widget.categoryId);
    var _list = json.decode(products.body);
    List<Recipe> results = [];
    _list["data"].forEach((data) {
      var model = Recipe();
      model.id = data["id"];
      model.title = data["recipeTitle"];
      model.image = data["recipePhoto"];
      model.cookTime = data["cookTime"].toString();
      model.ingredients = data["recipeIngredient"];
      model.directions = data["recipeDirection"];
      results.add(model);
    });
    setState(() {
          _recipeListByCategory = results;
          isLoading = false;
    });
 }
```

Comment: You're welcome. Make sure you are implementing the answer which I edited now. Calling `setState` for every element is not best practice. So, at last `setState` the whole list.

Comment: Please can you help me? I want to add connectivity check functionality in this answer but  i am getting only circularProgress please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63665111/pass-widgets-in-connectivity-check-in-flutter/63665164?noredirect=1#comment112584078_63665164

Comment: Sure! But please post your latest code and your expected results in a new question.

Comment: please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/q/63675801/10588735

Answer (score 0):

```
Widget getGridView(){
    return _recipeListByCategory != [] ? GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
      ),
      itemCount: _recipeListByCategory.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return RecipeByCategory(
          this._recipeListByCategory[index],
        );
      },
    ) : Center(child: Text("No Data Found"),);
  }
```

or

```
Widget getGridView(){
    return (_recipeListByCategory?.length != 0) ? GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
      ),
      itemCount: _recipeListByCategory.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return RecipeByCategory(
          this._recipeListByCategory[index],
        );
      },
    ) : Center(child: Text("No Data Found"),);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @spycbanda same problem after checking both solutions.

Comment: This is because either your _recipeListByCategory is not reassigned, or your Widget is not refreshed, or may be both. Have you used setState((){ _recipeListByCategory = fetchedRecipes}); where fetchedRecipes are the recipes fetched after hitting the API get request

Comment: Please take a look into full code. I think isLoading function is not used properly.