# Pass Widgets in Connectivity check in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to implement internet connectivity check into my app and I used official [connectivity](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity) plugin and it is working great for displaying String Value but instead of showing string value in screen I want to display  different widgets for connected and disconnected.

Here What I am Using

```
//
Widget result;
//


body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: result != null ? 
        result : Text("unknown", style :
        TextStyle(fontSize: 30,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
```

```
void checkStatus(){
    Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) { 
      if(
        result == ConnectivityResult.mobile ||
        result == ConnectivityResult.wifi){
          Text("Connected", style:TextStyle(color:Colors.red));
        } else {
          Text("No InterNet", style:TextStyle(color:Colors.red));
        }
    });
  }
```

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkStatus();
  }
```

And I am Getting 'unknown' value

Comment: Please use `return Text(...)` instead of only widget

Comment: Getting error type 'Widget' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
class Sample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SampleState createState() => _SampleState();
}

class _SampleState extends State<Sample> {
  Widget result;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkStatus();
  }

  void checkStatus() async {
    var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
      result = Text("Connected to Mobile Network");
      setState(() {});
    } else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
      result = Text("Connected to WiFi");
      print("Connected to WiFi");
      setState(() {});
    } else {
      result = Text("Unable to connect. Please Check Internet Connection");
      setState(() {});
      print("Unable to connect. Please Check Internet Connection");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: result);
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting blank screen

Comment: add setState(() {}), since your listening to the connectivity add setstate so it will changed/rebuild its widget value.. so after your result = Text(); setState(() {});

Comment: Thanks for your answer. now it is working but how can we integrate real time network detection because it is not updating when turned off internet.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Use this package for checking Internet:
data_connection_checker:

And, Inside your stateful class create stream listener i.e and a boolean value.

```
StreamSubscription<DataConnectionStatus> listener; bool isConnected = true;
```

and Inside initState:

```
     @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
   

    listener = DataConnectionChecker().onStatusChange.listen((status) {
      switch (status) {
        case DataConnectionStatus.connected:
          print('Data connection is available. $status');
          setState(() {
            isConnected = true;
          });
      
          break;
        case DataConnectionStatus.disconnected:
          print('You are disconnected from the internet. $status');
          setState(() {
            isConnected = false;
          });
       
          break;
      }
    });
  }
```

Done, This will keep listening to changes in your internet status, Thus you can prompt user as you like. Cheers, Feel free to ask if confusion and if it helps upvote :D