# Make isLoading boolean function to false in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to integrate flutter connectivity check function in my app, and After integrating it is working great for all widgets but in my case for setState method it can not false isLoading method.

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool isLoading = true;
  Widget result;
  RecipeService _recipeService = RecipeService();
  List<Recipe> _recipeList = List<Recipe>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getRecipe();
    checkStatus();
  }

  _getRecipe() async {
    var dayRecipes = await _recipeService.getRecipeOfTheDay();
    var _list= json.decode(dayRecipes.body);
    List<Recipe> results = [];
    _list['data'].forEach((data) {
      var model = Recipe();
      model.id = data['id'];
      model.title = data['recipeTitle'];
      model.ingredients = data['recipeIngredient'];
      model.directions = data['recipeDirection'];
      model.cookTime = data['cookTime'].toString();
      model.image = data['recipePhoto'];
      results.add(model);
     });
      setState(() {
        _dayRecipeList = results;
        isLoading = false;
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("My Recipe"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: result
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here is Check method for internet, where I used homeItems() widget for displaying my content in case of connectivity

```
  void checkStatus() async {
    var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile || connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
      result = homeItems();
      setState(() {});
    } else {
      result = Text("Unable to connect. Please Check Internet Connection");
      setState(() {});
      print("Unable to connect. Please Check Internet Connection");
    }
  }
```

And Here is My homeItems widget, which is used in checkStatus method. as result = homeItems();

```
 Widget homeItems(){
    Center(
           child: isLoading
               ? CircularProgressIndicator(
                   backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                   strokeWidth: 10,
                 )
               : ListView(
                   children: [
                      Padding(
                       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                       child: Text("All Recipes",
                           style: TextStyle(
                               fontSize: 25,
                               color: Colors.red,
                               fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                     ),
                     RecipesOfDay(dayRecipeList: _dayRecipeList),
                     Padding(
                       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                       child: Text("All Recipes",
                           style: TextStyle(
                               fontSize: 25,
                               color: Colors.red,
                               fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                     ),

                   ],
                 ),
         );
  }
}
```

After running all app I am getting blank Screen without any error. Please take a look for solving this issue. Thank You

Comment: Did you tried executing `checkStatus();` and then  `_getRecipe();`, in `initState()`?

Comment: Yes. In above code I used in initState.

Comment: No, I mean first call `checkStatus()` and then call `_getRecipe()`.

Comment: Yes tried. Same problem

Comment: Yes tried. Same problem

Answer (score 0):

use try and finally. and set isLoading to false in finally